# Reading Cdata section in xml

Tags: .net, xml

I am working on metro apps where I am reading an xml file and displaying it.

I am able to read xml file but only the tag value is read. I have requirement of reading cdata section of xml.

I can achieve this with the help of `FileOpenPicker` but it opens all files of particular type and allows user to select one file I don't want that.

I want to directly open `.xml` file at specified location.

Comment: Was the answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is the C# example:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(yourXMLfile);  
var queryCDATAXML = from element in XTemp.DescendantNodes()
                    where element.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.CDATA
                    select element.Parent.Value.Trim();
```

Comment: thank u so much. now I have another issue.what I want is I want complete tag with its element  for example     <p color="Black" textAlpha="1" fontFamily="Minion Pro" fontSize="12" fontStyle="Regular" lineHeight="Auto" lineThrough="false" paragraphEndIndent ="0" paragraphSpaceAfter ="0" paragraphSpaceBefore ="0" paragraphStartIndent ="0"DCNoOfLines ="3">
    <span baselineShift="0" color="Black" textAlpha="1" 
     some data here    </span>
  </p> in this ex I want <span>some data here </span>

Comment: @user2243331 - "thank u so much" - better vote my answer up! =)

Comment: @user2243331 and update you question with the information you have posted here as a comment please.